# Особенности std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11

Вопрос по `std::move(T&& a)` (заголовок шаблона и возвращающее значение не писал осознанно).
При передаче `rvalue` типа `X`, для аргумента функции выведется тип `X&&`.

Если передавать `lvalue`, то тип а выведется как `X&` и произойдёт захват по ссылке. А как будет если выведется `X&&` для аргумента функции? Что здесь будет?

Comment: Вам в любом случае вернут `X&&`, где `X` - переданный тип с удаленными ссылками - см. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: Я знаю что в любом случае вернётся T&&

Comment: Тогда в чем ваш вопрос? Непонятно, что именно вам непонятно...

Comment: Я чуть скорректировал вопрос, но суть не изменилась.  Вопрос в том что X& a = var это захват по ссылке. А что будет в случае X&& a = var?

Answer (score 0):

Разница в & и && не такая большая как вым кажется. По сути и то и то ссылка. Ссылка && нужна для перегрузки одной и тоже функции, чтобы для rvalue вызывалась одна версия, а для & другая.

Во многих случаях это даёт плюс в производительности, т.к. вы перемещаете содержимое параметра функции в переменную. Вам не надо думать о вызывающий стороне, т.к. вам гарантированно, что параметр функии всё равно умрёт после вызова функции т.к. это rvalue. Для функций с & параметром, вы тоже можете не копировать, а перемещать содержимое, но тогда у вызывающий стороны, после вызова функции окажется "пусто" объект.
Если локальная (lvalue) переменная попадёт в функцию как && параметр, то функция выполнит все действия написанные в ней. Перменная будет валидна после этого, возможно содержимое будет пустым.

Небольшой пример:

```
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        data = new char[10];
    }
    ~A()
    {
        if (data)
        {
            delete[] data;
        }
    }


    char* data = nullptr;
};

void copy(A& a)
{
    printf("Copy&\n");
}

void copy(A&& a)
{
    // Переместили данные в другое место и обноулили указатель. 
    char* b = a.data;
    a.data = nullptr;
    // Чтобы не было утечки.
    delete[] b;
    printf("Copy&&\n");
}

A getA()
{
    return A();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    copy(a); //&
    copy(getA());//&&
    A&& b = std::move(a);
    copy(b); // &
    copy(std::move(a));//&&
    printf("a.data = %d\n", a.data);    

    return 0;
}
```

В результате a.data будет нулевым, т.к. copy&& переместил данные в другое место.

Comment: Выражение type& a = obj; - можно сказать что здесь происходит захват по ссылке. А в выражении type&& a = obj; что происходит? Тот же захват?

Comment: Да, с этим сложно посморить

Comment: А что такое захват по ссылке для rvalue? Разве есть ссылка на rvalue?

Comment: По сути && тоже захват по ссылке. Как минимум на уровне машинных команд и & и && одно и тоже. Вам наверное необходимо понять зачем вообще добавили поддержку && ссылок, тогда всё может быстро проясниться.

Comment: Может это поможет разобаться https://habrahabr.ru/post/226229/

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже что вас интересует сворачивание ссылок(reference collapsing).

Как известно rvalue ссылка рядом с типом, который выводится компилятором называется универсальной. Вот несколько примеров:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& value);

//---

auto&& var2 = var1;

//---

template<class T>
class Foo{
    typedef T&& type;
};
```

Называется она так потому что из-за механизма сворачивания ссылок она может превратиться как в rvalue ссылку так и в lvalue.

Суть механизма сворачивания ссылок в том, что в C++ не может быть ссылки на ссылку. Но может случится так, что компилятор выведет тип `T` как, скажем `int&`. Для таких случаев решили следующее:

- &  + &  = &
- &  + && = &
- && + &  = &
- && + && = &&

Ваш пример:

```
template<class T>
T&& move(T&& a);
```

Развернется как:

```
template<class T>
T&& move(X&& && a);
```

И ссылка на ссылку, согласно правилам, схлопнется в одну ссылку:

```
template<class T>
T&& move(X&& a);
```

Подробно об этом механизме [здесь](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не совсем это имел ввиду. Это я понимаю, вопрос в том что я не могу понять: если type& a = b - здесь происходит захват по ссылке объекта b. А что происходит при type&& a = b;? Тоже захват по ссылке?